# Cmail/XBoard won't allow move

Tags: correspondence-chess

I've recently started playing e-mail correspondence chess and I'm looking at Cmail/XBoard as a tool to play these games. Looking at the docs, I managed to get the right PGN tags for the game to be parsed and XBoard to launch and display the latest position.

XBoard will not allow any moves though. I can step through the game but not enter a new move.

Any idea on what could be wrong with the XBoard settings or the PGN input?

```
[Event "Email correspondence game"]
[Site "NET"]
[Date "2016.08.04"]
[Round "-"]
[White "Vergara, Rene"]
[Black "?"]
[Result "*"]
[WhiteNA "?"]
[BlackNA "email@host.com"]
[Mode "EM"]
[CmailGameName "rav-vs-Rene"]

1. e4
*
```

Comment: Can you provide a broken PGN to test?

Comment: This is the content generated by Cmail itself when I started a game and sent it to myself. If I pipe this back into Cmail, it reads the PGN and shows the move but it doesn't allow me to make the next move.

Answer (score 1):

Once you provide the email file to Cmail/XBoard, you need to switch to 'Edit Game' mode, in the Mode menu in order to record a move. Also, I had to switch out of 'Edit Game' mode in order to mail the move.